# Can I use a monster's sneak attack ability while polymorphed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, polymorph, sneak-attack

My spellthief (who possesses the type outsider) casts the spell *polymorph* to assume the form of a kelvezu (*Monster Manual II* 60, 61—2). Does my spellthief lose his normal sneak attack and gain the +8d6 sneak attack of the kelvezu form?

Comment: I think you may be asking two questions. The first regarding whether you gain the Kelvezu's sneak attack dice when polymorphed into one. The other seems to be about whether you keep your feats while polymorphed. I would recommend editing down to just one question and creating a new question for the other.

Comment: Combining those questions is reasonable, I think, but we do need to know how you are turning into a kelvezu—is that literally the _polymorph_ spell? Every form of changing forms is different, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified the situation of my character in the description first. My spellthief is a shade, so it is considered to be of the outsider type, in this way I can use polymorph (as a spellthief's 4th level spell) to turn myself into a Kelvezu.

Answer (score 4):

There are really two parts to this question. First:

> Does my spellthief lose his normal sneak attack?

**NO:** [Polymorph](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/polymorph.htm) and [Alter Self](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/alterSelf.htm) are explicit in what you "lose" when you change shape, and those things are:

- Racial supernatural and spell-like abilities for which you do not have the necessary body parts
- Racial EX attacks and special qualities
- Racial physical qualities (replaced with new form's)
- Spellcasting (if the new form cannot provide the necessary component)

Sorry, i originally answered this for a rogue and not a spellthief, but the answers are unchanged. A spellthief's sneak attack is a class-granted EX attack. As such, it is not lost when using polymorph.

Second:

> Do I gain the +8d6 sneak attack of the kelvezu form?

**YES:** The sneak attack for a spellthief explicitly states:

> If a spellthief gets a sneak attack bonus from another source (such as rogue levels), the bonuses on damage stack.

This is actually just a restatement of the trend that all sources of sneak attack tend to stack.